# Midori change URL without new tab

Tags: python, midori

I am trying to change the url of the midori browser after predefined intervals.

```
import os
import subprocess
import time

cmdline = ["midori", "-e", "Fullscreen", "-a","http://www.foo.bar"]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmdline)
time.sleep(10)
cmdline = ["midori", "-e", "Fullscreen", "-a","http://www.bar.foo"]
p = subprocess.call(cmdline)
```

In addition I have set the the `Preferences ->Open New Page in -> Current tab`. But still it open new window for the second `subprocess.call()`.

How can I open the new url in the same tab(no multiple tabs) on the same browser window?

Comment: You need to realize that the invocation of `subprocess.call` in the proposed code snippet is not sending information to the already running instance of `midori` but starting a new one.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681715/whats-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-call-how-do-you-use-them-to) that both `subprocess.Popen` and `subprocess.call` essentially do the same thing (more or less). What you actually want to accomplish is to start `midori` just once and then send this very instance new commands. Which however I cannot answer.

Comment: I'd recommend to ask this at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ as it is really not Pi specific and might get better and faster answers over there.